# Return DOM element from JavaScript to Java and optimize click

Tags: javascript, java, dom

I want return element from DOM (JavaScript) to Java code and optimize click action on it.

Firstly I search element(button) in document by JavaScript

```
var buttonToReturn = document.getElementById('actionButton');
```

When found it(be sure that the button exist), I returned the name `actionButton` by mapped function

```
ButtonFoundFunction(this, browser, "buttonFound"); - in Java code

buttonFound(`actionButton`); - in JavaScript
```

Get the returned button name - `actionButton` in Java code by `ButtonFoundFunction` which extend `BrowserFunction` and override `public Object function(Object[] arguments)...` and execute click on this element as below

```
browser.execute("document.getElementById('" + arguments[0] + "').click();");
```

but `document.getElementById(...)` search the button second time. So what is the problem ?

I want optimize it to search button once(only in JavaScript), return whole element to Java code(the `buttonToReturn`) and execute click on it without second search by `document.getElementById(...)`. I would like to the execute should look as below

```
browser.execute(arguments[0] + ".click();");
```

It means that I would execute in browser click on this element, not second time searching it.

I tried return the `buttonToReturn` but it do not work, `BrowserFunction` is not called(wrong type?). Maybe I should use other object for it in Java code instead `Object`?

```
          1. searchButton()
+------+   ------------->   +----------+
| Java |                    |JavaScript|
+------+   <-------------   +----------+
          2. buttonFound()
 ^
 |        
 3. browser.execute(arguments[0] + ".click();");
```

**EDIT**

`buttonToReturn` is `HTMLDivElement` and I can not returned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I can't pass a native JS object to Java.

When JavaScript looks like that:

```
var buttons = [];

var buttons[0] = document.getElementById(`actionButton`);
```

to execute click in Java it is enough by code:

```
browser.execute("buttons[0].click()");
```

Because `buttons` array is in SWT `Browser` cache.